# Rails 3 - Object.try syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How would I avoid nil checks using Object.try for the following?

```
<%= image_tag(PeriodState.where("sla_id = ?", sla.id).last.state.image_file) %>
```

I've tried .try many different ways, but still receive errors, so my syntax is off.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try` isn't really appropriate for this: whatever the outcome `image_tag` will always be called - so you might end up calling it with nil. You need to check whether the image exists first then create an image tag only in this case. So I would get the PeriodState in your controller and have a simple `if` in your view:

```
# in controller
@period_state = PeriodState.where("sla_id = ?", sla.id).last

# in view 
<%= image_tag(@period_state.state.image_file) if @period_state %>
```

Of course this won't work if either `state` or `image_file` could also be nil.

Comment: Thanks - I think I have another issue in the controller because I'm using @search:  `def index
    @search = Sla.search(params[:search])
    @slas = @search.all(:order => "fiscal_year DESC, project_name ASC")
 @period_state = PeriodState.where("sla_id = ?", @search.id).last
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @slas }
    end
  end` , so I'm not sure how to get the period_state for the slas... does that make sense?

Comment: Changed my controller to this:  `def index
    @search = Sla.search(params[:search])
    @slas = @search.all(:order => "fiscal_year DESC, project_name ASC").each {
  |s|
  @period_state = PeriodState.where("sla_id = ?", s.id).last
  }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @slas }
    end
  end`, but now I'm getting the same period_state for all slas... ugh

Comment: I got it to work by putting everything in the view:  `<% @period_state = PeriodState.where("sla_id = ?", sla.id).last %>
 <td><%= image_tag(@period_state.state.image_file) if @period_state.state %></td>`  Thanks!